# Glue Dynamic Frame is way slower than regular Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

In the image below we have the same glue job run with three different configurations in terms of how we write to S3:

1. We used a dynamic frame to write to S3
2. We used a pure spark frame to write to S3
3. Same as 1 but reducing the number of worker nodes from 80 to 60

- **All things equal, the dynamic frame took 75 minutes to do the job, regular Spark took 10 minutes. The output were 100 GB of data.**
- The dynamic frame is super sensitive to the number of worker nodes, failing due to memory issues after 2 hours of processing when slightly reducing the number of worker nodes. This is surprising as we would expect Glue, being an AWS service, to handle better the S3 writing operations.

The code difference was this:

```
if dynamic:
    df_final_dyn = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df_final, glueContext, "df_final")

    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=df_final_dyn, connection_type="s3", format="glueparquet", transformation_ctx="DataSink0",
    connection_options={"path": "s3://...", 
    "partitionKeys": ["year", "month", "day"]})
else:
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode", "dynamic")
    df_final.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").partitionBy("year", "month", "day")\
             .save("s3://.../")
```

[image]

Why such an inefficiency?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but here's some input based on my experience.

There are some optimisations that can be made when reading from S3 in Glue.
Here's a nice post on the subject from AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-memory-management-in-aws-glue/

These are the ones we have had luck with for having stable and performant Glue jobs using dynamic-frames:

```
'useS3ListImplementation': True
'groupFiles': 'inPartition'
'groupSize': '<some-int>' // some value between 1048576 and 134217728
```

For preventing memory-failures in Glue and to increase parallelisation, the `groupSize` is a key config. Without it, Glue somehow dynamically calculates the group-size which from my experience can cause random failures when tasks get too much data.

Another thing to try is to make the Glue and Spark tests more equivalent: E.g skip 'transformation_ctx' since it might cause some overhead.